# File input behaviour in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, file-upload, openfiledialog

I have noticed a difference in behaviour between chrome and IE of handling file input clicks.

jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsJCU/).

In Chrome, clicking anywhere on the input (text or button bit) triggers the file dialogue.

In IE (testing on 7), you have to click on the actual button, not the text bit.

The problem is that I'm using a transparent file input on top of a regular text box. Clicking on the text box should open the dialog. In Chrome this is working fine, as the total size of the input is the same size as my text box.

In IE it doesn't work properly as the user needs to be clicking on the actual button part of the transparent file input.

Any ideas of how to fix this??

Thanks

Comment: Awwww... isn't this a really hacky workaround that might get disabled in future browser generations for security reasons? No chance of using something else, like a stylable Flash based uploader?

Comment: no, no chance of using flash. If it gets disabled in future browsers it's only going to be a 10 minute job to change it, until then I want to at least try to give my users a decent looking interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to trigger a click event on the `file` input box..

Maybe adding a click handler on the underlying textbox which issues the click event to the file box.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/MqbrV/

It does not work in Firefox (*but the default action should be enough*) and Opera (*where none works*).

Comment: this wasn't exactly what i was looking for but gave me the clue i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at how these guys have done it: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/

The strategy is the the same, overlay a custom designed file input over a standard one and get the user to interact with the standard one.

They have written a small hack to support the click for IE and Opera, using jQuery to bind a click event explicitly.

See: http://dwpe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fileinput/js/jQuery.fileinput.js (Line 52)

Comment: actually, the code on line 52 is for triggering the change event in the file input, it looks like IE doesn't handle that properly either. So your post was very useful to me anyway, as I needed to deal with that issue too. If you look nearer the bottom of that file, you see they deal with handling the click by actually moving the file input onmousemove in the fake control, so the click always happens over the correct place.